# JerseyConfig and @Profile to hide a REST endpoint

Tags: spring, rest, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to hide a REST endpoint based on runtime configuration in Spring and Jersey. The most straightforward way is to throw the `NotFoundException` from the controller itself but maybe there's more kosher. The controller is registered in the constructor of the config class which extends `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`.

I thought of using the `@Profile` annotation on the controller but I can still access the endpoint. When I hit that endpoint, I get the following error:

```
o.g.j.s.s.SpringComponentProvider - None or multiple beans found in Spring context
```

but then Jersey manages to access that controller, which I confirmed by attaching a debugger to the Spring process. So Jersey does not honor the `@Profile` setting.

On a separate note, I also have Swagger plugged into Jersey and when accessing the definition endpoint (`.../swagger.json`) I can see the endpoint provided by the `@Profile`-disabled controller.

Is there anything better I can do here is is throwing the `NotFoundException` the best option?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Sorry, I thought I saw that you were using Spring Boot. The following answer is only relevant for Spring Boot.

---

`@Profile` is only good for Spring bean registration, but you are still registering the service with Jersey as a resource. What you can do is use a [`ResourceConfigCustomizer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/ResourceConfigCustomizer.html) and add the `@Profile` to the customizer. This way it will only register the resource with Jersey `ResourceConfig` if the correct profile is active.

```
@Component
@Profile("..")
public class MyResourceConfigCustomizer implements ResourceConfigCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ResourceConfig config) {
        config.register(MyResource.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Solved my use case! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I wasn't more specific.

Comment: Note that if your Jersey resource class is also a Spring component (which is not required), then you should still add the `@Profile` to the class also, because even though the resource will not be registered with Jersey when the profile will not be active, you will still have a the Spring bean laying around for no reason.

Comment: Thanks. I applied @Profile to both the customizer and the controller. I wanted to make sure it wouldn't get accidentally expired even without jersey